# Shell script to read changes from GIT repo and then commit these changes to SVN

Tags: git, bash, shell, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have no shell scripting experience.
I want to create a shell script that will fetch changes from GIT and commit these changes to the SVN repository.

After searching a lot online and reading this link: 
[Shell script to check git for changes and then loop through changed files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13715544/shell-script-to-check-git-for-changes-and-then-loop-through-changed-files)

i could come up with the following...

```
#!/bin/sh

#checks if there are any changes
if ! git --git-dir="/dir/.git" diff --quiet
then
    # do stuff...
    git --git-dir="/dir/.git" diff-tree ORIG_HEAD.. | \
    while read srcmode dstmode srcsha dstsha status srcfile dstfile
    do
        # do something with $srcfile and $dstfile
    done
fi
```

I guess the above will get changes from the GIT repo. Am I on the right path here?
And now in the loop I want to commit the changes obtained from GIT.

How can this be done ?

I will be adding this script in Jenkins and it will execute as a post-build action.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't use `git-svn`?

Comment: Hi. Actually we are using Jenkins server for builds. So I want to create post-build script which will execute after each build.

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use `git-svn` as [Ju Liu suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17313296/shell-script-to-read-changes-from-git-repo-and-then-commit-these-changes-to-svn#comment25111014_17313296). Let's say you have the following setup:

- Git repository at `/repos/project.git`.
- Standard `branches`, `tags`, `trunk` directory structure at `http://svn/project`.

To copy commits from the `git` repository to the `project` Subversion trunk:

1. Create a Git repository from Subversion:

   ```
   cd /repos
   git svn clone --stdlayout --revision 1:HEAD --no-minimize-url http://svn/project
   ```
2. Add the `git` repository as a remote:

   ```
   cd project
   git remote add /repos/project.git
   ```
3. Get the `git` commits you want. You can for example `git pull` and then `git rebase [commit-id-of-the-subversion-head]` to remove unwanted commits, or use `git cherry-pick` to get only some of them in the first place.
4. When you have the commits you want, `git svn dcommit` to commit to Subversion.

You can keep both `git` repositories, and just update `/repos/project` with `git svn rebase` before doing additional `pull`s or `cherry-pick`s from `/repos/project.git`.

Comment: Thanks :) this approach definitely looks a lot more easy. But if I had to write a shell script for it, would it be easy to write one ?

Comment: Probably not very difficult (the commands wouldn't be much more complicated than the ones above), but the real question is why you're copying commits and using two VCSes in the first place.