# git diff --name-only with ignore space seems to be broken

Tags: git, diff, space, ignore

I have a repository where there are many files that only have EOL whitespace changes, but some have actual changes.  I am trying to craft an alias to open diffs of only the files with real changes in vim tabs, and as part of that I am running a `git diff --name-only ...` command to get a list of files that have changed so I can open them in tabs.

My problem is that `--ignore-space-at-eol`, `--ignore-space-change`, and `--ignore-all-space` seem to do nothing when combined with `--name-only`.

When I run the following command nothing is printed out (`my_file` has a CR/LF change):

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol my_file
```

But when I run this I get `my_file` printed out:

```
git diff --ignore-space-at-eol --name-only my_file
```

Is there some way to get only the names of files that have no whitespace changes?  This seems like a bug to me, but I haven't been able to find a similar issue.

I am on git version 2.25.0

Comment: `git diff --name-only` lists files without looking into the content. You cannot filter the list by the content of the files.

Comment: @phd I see that that is what it does, but to me that violates my expectations (especially since it does not inform me that those other flags are invalid for `--name-only`).  I'm open to suggestions for alternative approaches.

Comment: You might try reporting this as a bug with the Git project folks. They may ignore you, but if they get enough people griping about this—I know *why* Git does this internally, but I don't think Git *should* do this, but I personally don't care enough to fix it myself :-)—maybe someone will actually fix it.

Comment: @torek And if the OP choses to open a bug, it would be better to do so with Git 2.27: it comes with **[bugreport](https://github.com/git/git/blob/238b439d69890980dafc5154895d425cb4cf4a5e/Documentation/git-bugreport.txt)**, that I mention at the end of https://stackoverflow.com/a/10733251/6309)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to:

- get the list of files first: `git diff -–name-only`
- then for each file do a `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol my_file`

But if you want to perform the second diff only if there are actual changes, wrap that second diff with a test ([as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13715727/6309)), using the [`--quiet` option](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt---exit-code):

```
if ! git diff --quiet --ignore-space-at-eol my_file; then
    git diff --ignore-space-at-eol my_file
fi
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and this works when using the native diffing capabilities in git.  I think I will need a more sophisticated script to collect the names in an array so that I can pass them to vim, but that is my own application and somewhat outside the scope of this question.  I believe the use of --quiet will allow me to do what I need.

Comment: @DrEsperanto Great! Still, I believe what you have mentioned with `git diff --ignore-space-at-eol --name-only my_file` is a bug.

Answer (score 7):

I happened to stumble onto a similar problem recently and also found that using the `--name-only` option will not work with either `--ignore-all-space` or `--ignore-blank-lines`.

As someone in the comments pointed out this is due to `--name-only` only checking if a file has changed but not calculating the actual change. What I found is that you can use the `--stat` option instead, since this will calculate the actual changes to files.

So for getting a list of files that have changed while ignoring whitespace changes you might use something like the following:

`git diff --stat --ignore-all-space --ignore-blank-lines --diff-filter=M <branchname>`